# How to insert UIImageView between two sections of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have design in my application like I have 4 sections in my UITableView and I need to insert a UIImageView and UILabel between the sections of the same table. Is it possible to do the same?

Kindly show me a path.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger) section
```

You may need to enclose the image view and the label in a IUView container and return the container from one of these methods. It depends on what and how exactly you'd like to present them.

Answer (score 2):

Is your table style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`?

If it is so, use `viewForHeaderInSection:` or `viewForFooterInSection:` method of `UITableViewDelegate`. create a view, add your image and label to the view, and return  to the view from either of the above two delegate methods. I guess, you are using the image and label as header of the section. So, `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented in that manner and it shows the image as per my need.Thank you for showing the path,I am showing the code in case anybody else is in need.Thank you.

```
   -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger) section
    {
            UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,320,40)];
            UIImageView *imgAdbar = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(header.frame.origin.x,header.frame.origin.y,header.frame.size.width,header.frame.size.height)];
            [imgAdbar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ad2.png"]];
            [header addSubview:imgAdbar];
            header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            return header;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to make a custom view which has four separate tables with one section each and put the imageview and the uilabel between each of the tables.